# slicing object in move constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, move-constructor

When a variable is passed as xvalue to a move constructor, one should assume that after execution the variable is in a "undefined" state; using it afterwards would incur in UB.
However, what will happen if an xvalue is "sliced" by (implicitly or explicitly) casting it to a base class? Would the variable still be partially "usable"?

Example:

```
#include <vector>

struct inA {
    std::vector<int> s;
};

struct A {
    std::vector<int> s;
    A(inA&& x) : s(std::move(x.s)) { }
};

struct inB : public inA {
    std::vector<char> t;
};

struct B : public A {
    std::vector<char> t;
    B(inB&& x) : A(std::move(x)), t(std::move(x.t)) { }
};

int main()
{
    inB v{std::vector<int>(3, 1), std::vector<char>(5, 'a')};
    B w(std::move(v));

    return 0;
}
```

(I use `std::vector` to have a non-trivial move constructor).

The constructor of `A` accepts a moving reference to a `inA` object. After that the moved `inA` object is in a undefined state and cannot be used:

```
std::vector<int> vec{3, 10};
A a(std::move(vec));
// vec[0] = 2; // UB!!
```

So far, so good.

Now, the constructor of `B` can accept a moving reference to a `inB` object, which is derived from `inA`.
By inheritance, the `B::B` forward the "slice" of `inB&& x` pertaining to the `inA`  to the constructor of the base class `A`. Then `B::B` initializes a member variable with the part of `inB` which was not inherited from `inA`.

Is this last step (i.e. `t(std::move(x.t))`) allowed?

On one hand, `x` has been already forwarded as moving reference to `A::A`, so it would be in a undefined state and using it afterwards incurs into UB.

On the other hand, `A::A` cannot touch the member variable `inB::t` because, due to slicing, it simply does not see it. So I would conclude that `inB::t` is still usable.

Comment: There is no [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) occurring in the code shown. Just references to different areas of the same object being passed around.  And yes, if you `move()` only a portion of an object, other portions remain in their original state. A move does not invalidate an object itself, only its content.

Comment: Object after move is in valid & undefined state. Using such object isn't UB. E.g. for vector you can call clear, and use this object again.